# Why doesn't ember.js event bubbling allow it to operate on the form

Tags: ember.js

The Action in my Controller gets called, but the event phase seems to terminate there, and the form is never updated.  This means the form's checkboxes and radio buttons do not get marked as selected.  Returning True, from the Action produces errors, and still doesn't update the form.  What exactly is going on with the event, and how can I allow the bubbling to continue onward to update the form?

[JSFiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xoqoh/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `{{action}}` helper calls `evt.preventDefault()`. You can skip this behavior using `preventDefault=true`. So in your code use the following:

```
{{action 'answerSupplied' answer.id question.id this preventDefault=false}}
```

[Updated jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yudenuqi/1/edit)

[preventDefault option documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_event-propagation)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for.  Now the form works as expected and the radio buttons stay grouped.